# XmlHttprequests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i am trying to get xmlhttp requests to a local server which inturn connects to outside network.i chrome i am getting an error
 **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com:58947 Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**
This is not a cross domain request since it is same domain but different port numbers.
I am getting a response of 0 instead of 200 in ff and chrome,but in IE its working perfectly.
Any help regarding this issue will save me!!

Comment: Different port means chance for whole different host. Chrome is right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give relative path instead of begin with http://mydomain.com